# Print generates a cell with style "Print"

Tags: evaluation

The Wolfram documentation for "[Print](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Print.html)" says the following:

> In a notebook, Print generates a cell with style "Print".

What does it mean by style `"Print"` since there is no style called `"Print"`?

Is there an implied meaning that is not obvious?

For example, the expression below creates a cell with style `"Input"`.

```
Print["Dog"]
```

For the first picture, notice how when Dog is selected, the format says `"Input"`.
I am still not clear what format style (`Input`?) it actually has.

[image]

---

For the second picture with `Show Expression` checked, I see `"Print"` which I assume is where the reference to `"Print"` is coming from?

[image]

The Wolfram documentation for `"Cell"` says the following:

> In any given notebook, a collection of possible cell styles is defined, typically with names such as  "Title",  "Section",  "Input", and  "Output".

There is no mention of `"Print"` as a style. Where is that documented?

Comment: I get a cell with style "Print", as checked by revealing the cell expression. How did you check the style?

Comment: The generated cell is the one where the value of your expression is displayed, not the one where you entered your expression.  To see the style, select the cell and [toggle the display](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/menuitem/ShowExpression.html).

Comment: I added pictures to the original question. I tried to clarify the question (using your responses) by asking for further details. Thanks

Comment: I cannot reproduce what you show. The formatting toolbar never shows a style name for a Print cell for me, no matter which part of the cell I select. (Normally you should select the cell bracket).  I tried this in versions 10.0 and 11.2.  The available styles are defined by the stylesheet. You can define arbitrary ones, so there won't be a list in the documentation. Most styles are not listed in the menu, and are not meant to be applied explicitly. Only those are which have the `MenuSortingValue` option set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the notebook menus, pick `Format > Edit Stylesheet`. Click on `Default.nb`, then click on `Core.nb`.  Open `Styles for Input and Output Cells`.  Select `Local Definition for Style "Print"` and toggle the cell display (`Ctrl-Shift-E`). hth.